# Vim run shell and see output

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to run an unsaved buffer in a shell command and have a history of the output

```
console.log("test")
```

Then, `:w !node` does what is expected, `test` is outputted, but once I click enter, the output disappears, and doesn't even show in `:messages:`

How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you open a Vim buffer and type in one or more shell commands each on "his" own line. Like:

```
  ls /home
  ls /root
```

Then you can type the command:
:%!bash

and not only will it run the commands on each line one after the other, it will also overwrite the buffer with the output of each command in chronological order, then you can do whatever you want with it :-)

I hope it was helpful :)

BTW: if you want to run a command in Vim and get the output in your buffer, then you can just double tap the exclamation mark in NORMAL MODE and the command line in the bottom will show
`:.!`
then you just type in your command and press enter. :)

easy peachy lemon squeeze :)

*note: I learned that last one by mistake*

Answer (score 0):

1. What `:w !cmd` does it pipes your current buffer contents into `cmd`'s stdin. When you don't need this you should simply execute `:!cmd` instead.
2. `:messages` serve to show an important log data printed by specially dedicated `:echom[sg]` command, not some random stuff from terminal windows. So the output from "node" process will not and should not ever get there.
3. You can put the process' stdout into the current buffer by using `:r[ead]` command, e.g.

   ```
   :r !node
   ```

Comment: I do need the buffer's content as the file for the command. If I run `:r !node` nothing happens, I need the buffer to be passed as a file to the `node` command

Comment: @Moshe If you need to redirect both stdin & stdout you should use `:h system()` instead.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I need. I have an unnamed buffer, I'd like to keep it that way. I want to run the code inside the buffer in a terminal, and *see* the output. The problem is, when I hit enter, the output disappears, and I can't see it unless I run the command again. I need a way to see the output after I click enter.

Comment: @Moshe Isn't it clear that in order to see something you have to save it somewhere first?

Comment: ok, is there a way to pipe the output to `echom` so I can see it in messages?

Comment: @Moshe As I already said, do something by `system()`. However, your whole question now sounds like a sort of "xy"-problem to me. Learn something about quickfix-list and try to make use of existing mechanisms, rather than re-inventing the wheel.